# Modal dialog appears in fullscreen instead of as a dialog box

Tags: abap, dynpro

My program has two dynpro screens. From the first screen the user can call a popup showing the details of a customer by double-clicking on the customer number.

My problem is that the popup shows up in fullscreen despite being set as a "Modal dialog box" in its properties and being called with the `CALL SCREEN 550 STARTING AT xa ya ENDING AT xb yb` statement from the first screen's PAI module.

Is there anything else I could forget ? I'm running my program from SE80 by pressing F8 if that matters.

Comment: You didn't forget anything. The most probable is that it doesn't happen exactly as you think. Otherwise it's an ABAP bug. Create a separate program to make sure it works, then check your main program again.

Comment: Maybe you didn't activate the screen and/or put the wrong dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

CALL SCREEN 550 STARTING AT xa ya ENDING AT xb yb

I guess if the dimensions are bigger than the screen it automatically turn into full screen, or when you choose Zero.
try at first this and then adjust it later:

```
 CALL SCREEN 550 STARTING AT 1 1 ENDING AT 10 10
```